# javascript wont find the id/class of html/javascript imported code with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, css

i´m building a search system for this petshop software web base, the thing is that i search for a name, than send the name with XMLHttpRequest to php page that execute the query and return me the results and display them at my search page,until here is ok. the information that php page returns to search page goes like this:

```
<?php
    $query = "selec ...
    $queryName = mysqli_query...
    while($fetchNames = mysqli_fetch_array...
    ?>
      <a class="profile">
        <div id="clientInfo"><?php echo $fetchNames[0]; ?></div>
      </a>
    <?php  } 
?>`
```

i try to acess the html class .profile imported on searchpage.php:

```
`<script>
document.querySelector('.profile').addEventListener('click',function=(){
alert('js code works!');
});
</script>
</body>`
```

i tryed to import it with the results of php query page right after the end of while loop, even with  the window.onload=func...  it won't work!

javascript won't work at the imported document, it can't see the class to display the alert. how can i work around this issue?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have dynamically-generated elements, you'll need to make use of [**event delegation**](https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/part-4-what-is-event-delegation-in-javascript-f5c8c0de2983) and target an element that exists on page load, and work down from there. You haven't mentioned any parent elements in your question, so I'll target `<body>` in my answer, as this *always* exists on page load.

As you're shifting the `eventListener` up the hierarchy, you need to ignore clicks other than the desired element. This can be achieved with **[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)** and **[`.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)**:

```
if (document.querySelector('.profile').contains(event.target)) { }
```

So your final code would look like:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (document.querySelector('.profile').contains(event.target)) {
    alert('js code works!');
  }
})
```

The above ensures that when you click on your dynamically-generated elements your `alert()` will fire, but it won't fire when you click on any other element.

Comment: It works the the first class, the rest of ids/class still not showing as it is a client form with names, streets,city etc and the cliente id auto increment was need to be picked by on click =(, but ill keep trying with this solution in mind...

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two different methods. The first one is that you can write javascript codes after the html code. or wait for the document to be loaded using 'document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)'

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('.profile').addEventListener('click',function=(){
        alert('js code works!');
    });
})
```